# What does @INC stand for in perl?

Tags: perl

I was surprised that I was unable to find an answer to such a simple question. Is the answer so obvious that nobody's ever had to ask before? I can only guess it might stand for "included" but  I really have no idea. A reference would be nice, if you have one.

**EDIT:** I know what `@INC`'s function and role is in Perl. I'm asking *why is it called INC.*

Comment: it is the include path for perl modules

Comment: @Aerovistae — Downvotes are not close votes. The suggested reasons for downvotes are lack of research effort, being unclear, or not being useful.

Comment: Perldoc exactly says that: *include path*. It's called `INC` probably to save keystrokes. Remember, perl programmers are *lazy* by virtue. :-)

Comment: By the lack of any mention of it (as you note), I'd conclude that it indeed stands for plain _include_.

Comment: @Aerovistae Jens' first comment told you what it stands for.  It's the **INC**lude path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using the excellent `perldoc` utility?

```
$ perldoc -q INC
[...]
   How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?
   Here are the suggested ways of modifying your include path, including environment
   variables, run-time switches, and in-code statements:
[...]
```

Comment: `perldoc perlvar` has more info.